# Looping problems

Tags: c++, loops, visual-c++, code-snippets

Visual C++ keeps aborting my loop. string l1 is 80 chars long. For some reason, the code gets through one iteration of the main loop and then a window appears saying "Debug Error...R6010 -abort() has been called" which terminates the program.

```
for(int i=1;i<80;i++)
{
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, green);

    for(int j=0;j<i;j++)
    {
        cout<<l1.at(j);
    }

    SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole,norm);

    for(int k=i;k<80;k++)
    {
        cout<<l1.at(k);
    }

    Sleep(100);
    system("CLS");
}
```

Comment: Please post the error message as well.

Comment: one iteration of which loop?

Comment: define 'kicks the bucket'

Comment: run it with the debugger and you see exactly where the assert kicks in

Comment: try to use string length of l1, istead of k<80;

Comment: Are you sure your `i1` string is 80 characters long ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
int len = strlen(l1) ;
for(int i=1;i<len;i++)
{
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, green);

    for(int j=0;j<i;j++)
    {
        cout<<l1.at(j);
    }

    SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole,norm);

    for(int k=i;k<len;k++)
    {
        cout<<l1.at(k);
    } 

    Sleep(100);
    system("CLS");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are exceeding the bounds of the string you are passing. Why have you hard coded the value of 80 into your code?

Comment: How did you come to that conclusion?

Comment: well, if you try and return a character out of a out of the bounds of the defined string (ie a string is 15 characters long and you're trying to return the character in position 50), then the it'll throw an exception. ie as Himanshu coded below, you should only go to the end of string, no further, EVER.